# Best approach to sort and filter from two different databases in Spring REST API

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

So in the application of my project, we are showing data to the user in an excel type of format. For each record, we have a fixed set of columns, say 5. We are saving those data in PostgreSQL.

Other columns are dynamic and a user can create and delete them anytime for each record. So they are stored in DynamoDB.

Now the requirement is to give the users options to sort and filter the records and user can choose one or multiple number of columns to do so. For the columns which are stored in Postgres, we already have implemented this functionality by creating Dynamic SQLs based on the payload. But how can we add these results to DynamoDB results?

What is the best approach to solve this problem? Should I fetch the sorted results from Postgres and sorted results from Dynamo (in case the user selects sort and filter from both type of columns) and later try to merge them in my JAVA code? Or is there any other better solution to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you store the dynamic columns in a single `jsonb` column in the Postgres table and get rid of the additional database completely?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yes finally we are doing that. But still I wonder is is really possible to do sorting and filtering from two different DBs?